# Multiple Yearling badge awards

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

Why have I been awarded the *yearling* badge multiple times in the last few months?

I see the badge can be awarded multiple times, however, my understanding would this badge should only be awarded annually. Am I misunderstanding this?

[image: yearling badge awards]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yearling badge is simply calculated as:

```
reputation / number of years > 200.
```

You have been a member of the site for 9 years and you have just over 1,000 reputation therefore you are eligible for 5 Yearling badges. As you earn more reputation you'll get more badges until you hit 1,800 points at which they'll stop coming so quickly.

Comment: Copy, that makes sense.  Why does it change at 1,800? Just curious.

Comment: It doesn't. 1.800 is simply 200 * 9  where 9 is the number of years you've been a member. If you get more than 2,000 points you'll only get the next Yearling badge when you've been a member for 10 years.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Understood.

Comment: That sounds like an incredibly lazy programmer came up with this...and since this has no real-world (or even "fake internet points world") consequences, nobody ever fixed it. (not DIY specific, I'm sure it applies to all of StackExchange)

Comment: Plus, time dilation... and the inevitable slingshot maneuver around the planet.